# Получить пользователя с закодированным паролем

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Есть проект с использованием Spring Security. Пароль в базу данных приходит закодированным:

```
@Override
public void save(final User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userMapper.insert(user);
}
```

Есть форма логина:

```
<spring:url value="/user/login" var="userLoginUrl" />
<form action="${userLoginUrl}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">Логин</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">Пароль</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Войти</button>
</form>
```

И контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginUser(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) 
{
//      bookFormValidator.validate(book, result);   

    Map<String, Object> parms = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    final String login = request.getParameter("login");
    final String password = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("password"));
    parms.put("login", login);
    parms.put("password", password);
    logger.info(parms);
    User user2 = userService.login(parms);
    logger.info(user2);
    model.addAttribute("user", user2);

    return "redirect:/book/books";
}
```

Но он кодирует в иное значение. В базе пароль "001" в виде `$2a$10$zeDTEy2IZp9Tw6NN2I.09eqIQa7MQJVUWZRE.aLt3HVFf04WXay2K`, а мне приходит `$2a$10$30/dW02bpqD8p1ahP1Ewpe8syRGgQtpra7tE9CEcXF8N6NxxjoP1C`.

Как корректно сделать получение данных?

Comment: Это хорошо, когда при каждом кодировании одного и того же значения получается разный хэш. Чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: У вас при сохранении user, там какой пароль приходит в метод save? Закодированный или нет?

Comment: Куда приходит пароль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь проверить, что введённый пользователем пароль совпадает с сохранённым в базе захэшированным значением, то делается это так

```
String password = request.getParameter("password");
if (bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
    // Введён правильный пароль
}
```

Но ума не приложу зачем вы это делаете вручную, если Spring Security предоставляет свой form login с точно такой же функциональностью.

Comment: Пишет "Empty encoded password" почему-то.

Comment: Насчёт form login не знал.

Comment: Проверяйте, что `user.getPassword()` возвращает.

Comment: В User написано public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }. При этом ничего не возвращает. final User user = new User();
     logger.info(user.getPassword());

Comment: Вот и выясняйте почему у вас `getPassword` ничего не возвращает. Видимо, вы `user` из БД как-то неправильно извлекаете. Но это уже отдельный вопрос.